# Difference between nice level and systemctl CPUShares property

Tags: systemd, cgroups, nice

As I understand it (please correct me if I'm wrong),

```
systemctl set-property ... CPUShares=some_value
```

limits the cpu time for an entire cgroup unit. If we instead want to limit cpu time for a process within that unit, we can run the process with

```
systemd-run ... nice=some_value
```

I'm wondering if there's some intrinsic difference between the concepts of the nice-value of a process and the CPUShares-value of a group of processes? Can we limit CPUShares of a process, or set the nice-value of a cgroup unit? When would we want to do one or the other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From reading `man systemd-run`, it will create a `service` and thus a `cgroup` on the fly. From reading `systemd.exec`, the `Nice=` directive will apply to *all* executed processes, so the way that `systmd` handles the concepts of `Nice=` and `CPUShares=` are very similar.

My understanding of the relationship is that it has to do with history. `nice` has existed for a listed a couple of decades and always applied to specific processes.

On the other hand, the concept of `cgroups` and the idea of applying `CPUShares=` to a process group is much a newer concept but accomplishes the same goal.

I expect `systemd` supports `Nice=` for historical compatibility.

I would use whichever one you are comfortable with, but not both to avoid confusion. If you have no preference, I would use the newer `CPUShares=` concept.

Comment: Beware, using CPU shares and nice values are likely to result in very different behaviors on "recent" distributions using systemd default cgroups (Debian 9 is one of those). See `sched(7)` : "Under group scheduling, a thread's nice value has an effect for scheduling decisions only relative to other threads in the same task group." A cgroup being such a task group. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 15):

On Linux,

- a nice value applies to a [task](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31595/are-linux-kernel-threads-really-kernel-processes/317759#317759), that is a process or thread (see link for disambiguation),
- a "CPU shares" value applies to a *task group* (for example: a *cgroup*).

The default non-realtime Linux' task scheduler (CFQ), distributes CPU time "fairly" among the different cgroups. It will use the `cpu.shares` value of each cgroup (by default 1024), relative to other cgroups' `cpu.shares` values, to grant more or less CPU time to each cgroup (more shares = more CPU bandwith).

Now, **within each cgroup**, a task's nice value will be used to grant it more or less CPU time, relative to other tasks' nice values **within the same cgroup**.

[sched(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html) says:

> Under group scheduling, a thread's nice value has an effect for scheduling decisions only relative to other threads in the same task group.

---

Side notes:

- a *task group* is a cgroup or an autogroup (see [sched(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html)),
- autogrouping may be disabled by defaut on your Linux distribution, check with `cat /proc/sys/kernel/sched_autogroup_enabled`,
- task groups can have hierarchical relationships (cgroups within a cgroup) that I *guess* the CFQ task scheduler considers to distribute CPU time,
- "recent" distributions may be using systemd to put tasks in cgroups by default (try `systemd-cgtop` and `systemd-cgls`).