# Why does a kernel thread have a PID?

Tags: linux

In Linux, a kernel thread have a PID:

[image]

Why is that? Is a kernel thread considered to be a process? And does a "normal" thread also have a PID?

Comment: http://opensourceforu.com/2011/08/light-weight-processes-dissecting-linux-threads/ should help

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31595/are-kernel-threads-really-kernel-processes

Answer (score 6):

They are poorly named.  Kernel threads in linux are processes (not actual threads) that run in kernel space rather than user space.

Comment: A process have many threads, does a kernel thread have many threads also?

Comment: @paul Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34959506/4941495

Comment: Kernel threads do not run in their own address space. Since the usual definition of a thread (vs. a process) is that related threads are executed in a shared address space, I think thread is a more appropriate term than process here.

Comment: @Johan Myréen A kernel thread has a PID as I have shown, but does a "normal" thread also have a PID?

Comment: @paul - "Normal" thread too has a PID, which is inherited from the creator process/thread (the one that called pthread_create() to launch it).