# Meaning of the term "process", "thread" and "task_struct" in Linux

Tags: linux, process, thread

In my knowing, a thread is an execution flow of a process and all the threads of a process share some common structures. Furthermore, in modern PC the CPU executes only threads, not processes.

What I don't undertand is the meaning of term **process** and **thread** in Linux. Linux really distinguish between process and thread? And which is the role of the **task_struct** structure?

I've read that Linux schedules task_struct for execution, so I thought that task_struct represent a thread and not a process, but looking inside the [definition of task_struct](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/sched.h) I saw that there is a reference to the children of task_struct. A thread can really have a child?

Comment: I've found a very interesting explanation in the first answer of this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31595/are-linux-kernel-threads-really-kernel-processes?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

On a user level a `process` belongs to the OS. The `process`, has a copy of environment and standard file descriptors (stdin, stdout, stderr), which are inherited from the OS. `Threads` are belong to a process, and several threads belonging to the same process are sharing environment and file descriptors of that process.

And yes, both processes and threads can have children. The word `child` here is just referring to a new process/thread which was created by OS on a request from an existing process/thread.

`task_struct` is a thingy which makes processes and threads possible. It is how they are made inside. But on a user level, there is no access to task_struct. If you writing your own kernel - then sure you would have to work with it, and with the scheduler.

So if you dive into the kernel and/or how CPU works - then yes, there is no real difference between `process` and `thread`, since they are done by the same actual real life *process*. The difference is only on a user level, in how the actual application works.

I would suggest you to obtain a copy and read "Modern Operating Systems" by Andrew Tanenbaum, [https://www.amazon.com/Modern-Operating-Systems-Andrew-Tanenbaum/dp/013359162X/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013359162X)
It is the best textbook on the subject.